# Specify ip to Docker container failed

Tags: docker, redis, redis-sentinel, weave

I have two machines(A,B) with Ubuntu 16.0.4.
Both installed docker(version 18.03.0-ce) and weave(2.3.0).
When I try to start the redis docker container with a specified ip:

```
docker run --name redis-master --net weave --ip 192.168.30.11 -d redis:5.0.8 redis-server --appendonly yes
```

It works fine on machine A while failed on machine B, and the error message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid address 192.168.30.11: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets.
```

On machine A, the docker network list:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
f5365db452bd        bridge              bridge              local
cda951aee0a8        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
38511d6122df        host                host                local
6e64da3a25e2        none                null                local
8d74a493f63e        weave               weavemesh           local
```

On machine B, the docker network list:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
d528e620daef        bridge              bridge              local
c4fffd9aa891        host                host                local
02731d6f3d25        none                null                local
ef57e48e09ec        weave               weavemesh           local
```

It confuses me that on machine A, the network 'docker_gwbridge' will appear after run the 'docker run --net weave --ip xxxx', but on machine B, no network 'docker_gwbridge'.

Could anyone help me, where does the 'docker_gwbridge' come from?